# translate form range value output into text

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I made this simple form. Now I’m looking for a way to translate the output into text.

- For `x.value equal 1`, display "hello"
- For `x.value equal 21`, display "world"
- For `x.value equal 202`, display "Good day"
- ...

How can I do this? I guess I need some JS?

```html
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(quality.value)+parseInt(time.value)+parseInt(budget.value)">
   
   <label for="quality"><b>Quality</b></label><br/>
Low <input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="quality" step="1"> High
    
   <br/><br/>

   <label for="time"><b>Time</b></label><br/>
Relax <input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0" id="time" step="10" list="timemarks"> Stress
   <datalist id="timemarks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>20</option>
</datalist>
    
   <br/><br/>

   <label for="budget"><b>Budget</b></label><br/>
Low <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" id="budget" step="100" list="budgetmarks"> High
<datalist id="budgetmarks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>100</option>
  <option>200</option>
</datalist>
    
   <br/><br/>
    
   <b><output name="x" for="quality time budget"></output>
   
</form>
```

Comment: yes you need to use JS as HTML does not evaluate mathematical expressions.

Comment: Given that you are trying to get some specific output, please clarify what `1 > "hello", 21 > "world", 202 > "Good day" etc.` means exactly. What is your algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(value1, value2, value3){
var total = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) + parseInt(value3)
var message = ""
switch(total){
case 0:
  message = "Good";
  break
case 1: 
  message = "Hello";
  break
case 2: 
  message = "World";
  break
case 20: 
  message = "Good Good";
  break
case 21: 
  message = "Hello Hello";
  break
case 22: 
  message = "World World";
  break
case 100: 
  message = "life life life";
  break
case 101: 
  message = "cool cool cool";
  break
case 102: 
  message = "know know know";
  break
case 110: 
  message = "what what what";
  break
case 111: 
  message = "why why why";
  break
case 112: 
  message = "how how how";
  break
case 120: 
  message = "how how how";
  break
 
//there is 3^3(27) cases ...

}

//...
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(quality.value)+parseInt(time.value)+parseInt(budget.value)">
   
   <label for="quality"><b>Quality</b></label><br/>
Low <input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="quality" step="1" onchange="myFunction(quality.value,time.value,budget.value)"> High
    
   <br/><br/>

   <label for="time"><b>Time</b></label><br/>
Relax <input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0" id="time" step="10" list="timemarks" onchange="myFunction(quality.value,time.value,budget.value)"> Stress
   <datalist id="timemarks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>20</option>
</datalist>
    
   <br/><br/>

   <label for="budget"><b>Budget</b></label><br/>
Low <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" id="budget" step="100" list="budgetmarks" onchange="myFunction(quality.value,time.value,budget.value)"> High
<datalist id="budgetmarks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>100</option>
  <option>200</option>
</datalist>
    
   <br/><br/>
    
   <b><output name="x" for="quality time budget"></output>
   
   <div id="output"> </div>
   
</form>
```

Comment: Hi edkeveked, Thank you! I try to get this work.... but sorry, no results. Also the code snippet doesnt seem to work. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DonaldRoos, it is working, it is only that I did not display all the 27 use cases possible. I updated my answer to add more use cases but not all the 27 :)

Comment: ok, I understand. But also the version with these two values doesn’t work, (sorry) (I’m using Firefox btw). It would be very helpful if you can make a working fiddle for me. Tnx a lot!

Comment: Run the snippet for values (0, 1, 2,20, 21,22 ...)

Comment: Cool! Thank you! (I owe you a beer)

Comment: You are welcome!  @DonaldRoos, do not forget to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, there really is no need for the `datalist` elements here. You've already got the `range` elements configured to step from the min to the max values correctly. I think the addition of them just confuses things at this point. Also, for what you are asking, stepping by `1` is best because we need to map the range values to array element indexes and we don't want to have to create indexes up to 200 when we only need to store 3 values in that array.

Next, you aren't really using `label` properly. It's not meant to label a section, it's meant to label a form element for accessibility. Also, you are using `b` and `br` for purely stylistic reasons, which isn't correct either. CSS handles that.

```js
// Get references to all the sliders in an array:
var frm = document.querySelector("form");
var out = document.getElementById("output");

// Set up number to word matrix:
var translate = {
  hiBye: ["hello", "goodbye", "see ya!"],
  toWho: ["people", "world", "universe"],
  greeting: ["Good morning", "Good day", "Good night"]
}

var sliders = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='range']");

frm.addEventListener("input", function(evt){
  var outputMessage = "";
  outputMessage = translate.hiBye[sliders[0].value];
  outputMessage += " " + translate.toWho[sliders[1].value];
  outputMessage += " " + translate.greeting[sliders[2].value];
  out.textContent = outputMessage;
});
```

```html
<form>
   
   <h1>Quality</h1>
   <div>Low <input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="quality"> High</div>
    
   <h1>Time</h1>
   <div>Relax <input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="time"> Stress</div>


   <h1>Budget</h1>
   <div>Low <input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="budget"> High</div>
  
   <div id="output"></div>
   
</form>
```

Comment: tnx scott! Your feedback is really welcome. But to be honest this is not exactly what i’m looking for.
I would like to controle the answers my self.
So for total value 1 "this is a answer for value 1" etc. value 222 "whoa, this is an answer to this value". Hopefully do you get what I mean. Tnx in advance

Comment: @DonaldRoos, this is exactly what my snippet does!